# Implementing Google Analytics 2 in IOS 6

Tags: ios6, google-analytics

While updating an app to ios 6, I found google analytics also needs update.

Following this method, I discovered it needs a ViewController which extends GAITrackedViewController class

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/

The guide mentions the following code in ViewDidLoad method, whereas I want it in some specific method. It doesn't seems to work. Kindly advise.

```
self.trackedViewName = @"My App";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GAITrackedViewController means giving up control over when [tracker trackView:viewName] gets called.  Setting the trackedViewName allows GAITrackedViewController to call [tracker trackView:self.trackedViewName] whenever it wants (presumably in viewDidAppear).

Also, GAITrackedViewController uses a KVO on this property, so view tracking doesn't get turned on until self.trackedViewName = @"view name" is performed.

Calling this in viewDidLoad assures that it's setup correctly by the time the first viewDidAppear gets called.